# decode twitter dinyurl to get full url link

Tags: php, twitter

I need to decode `tinyurl` coming from tweets,

```
<?php
$url = "http://t.co/vpDXYaXl7m";
$full = URLDecode($url);
echo "URL is $full";
function URLDecode($url) 
{
    $ch = @curl_init($url);
    @curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
    @curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, TRUE);
    @curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, FALSE);
    @curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $url_resp = @curl_exec($ch);
    preg_match('/Location: (.*)\n/', $url_resp, $i);
    if (!isset($i[1]))
    {
        return $url;
    }
    return $i[1];
}
?>
```

It gives the following error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare URLDecode() in F:\wamp\www\refresh\tinydecode.php 
on line 23
```

What is the issue? Is there any other way to decode this tiny urls?

Do I need any change if I'm using CURL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`urldecode()`](http://php.net/urldecode) is a built-in PHP function. You can't override those function names (well, you can, but not without special hacks). Change your function name to something different, say `MyURLDecode`.

```
function MyURLDecode($url) 
{
    $ch = @curl_init($url);
    @curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, TRUE);
    @curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, TRUE);
    @curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, FALSE);
    @curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    $url_resp = @curl_exec($ch);
    preg_match('/Location: (.*)\n/', $url_resp, $i);
    if (!isset($i[1]))
    {
        return $url;
    }
    return $i[1];
}
```

You might want to change your regular expression to `/Location:\s+(.*)\n/i` to account for lower case `location` headers and extra white-spaces.

Comment: thanks, but it does not give decoded url. p.s. http://codepad.org/Dr0eYmxs  . let me know if you have any idea for this

Comment: @user123: Did you update the regular expression as I said? The error is probably because CodePad doesn't have cURL enabled. See [this demo](http://codepad.viper-7.com/ofM5Zr). It outputs the decoded URL.

Comment: can you please explain logic behind `/Location:\s+(.*)\n/i`

Comment: @user123: `\s` matches any whitespace character. `i` modifier is for case-insensitive matching. The expression says: Match anything starting with Location, followed by one or more space character(s), then a random string upto a newline. We extract the random string -- that's new URL location.

Comment: and what about `location`?

Comment: @user123: Uh? Do you have any idea what the code in your question does? Or did you copy it from a random source?

Comment: sorry I copied it from http://myphpscriptz.com/php-scripts-tutorials/tinyurl-encode-and-decode-with-help-of-php-and-curl/